# WPF MVVMLight Setter not fired on binding TextBox when validation rule is invalid

Tags: wpf, validation, data-binding, mvvm-light, validationrules

I have a TextBox with binding on **Mo** property :

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Text">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Binding Path="Mo" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <validator:FloatPositiveValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

This one contains a validation rule which validate the control only if the value is not empty and greater than 0 :

```
public class FloatPositiveValidationRule : ValidationRule
{        
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string str = (string)value;

        if (str.Length > 0)
        {
            double mo = Double.Parse(str.Replace(".", ","));

            if (mo > 0)
                return new ValidationResult(true, null);
            else
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Must be greater than 0");
        }
        else
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Empty");
    }
}
```

In my view model, when the validation is false, the setter is not fired :

```
private double? _mo;
public string Mo
{
    get { return _mo.ToString(); }

    set
    {
        if (value != "")
            mo = double.Parse(value.Replace(".", ","));

        Set(ref _mo, mo);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to enter in the setter even if the validation is invalid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set `ValidationStep` property to `UpdatedValue`:

```
<validator:FloatPositiveValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"  />
```

This should make the validation rule run *after* the source property has been set.

But what you really should do is to remove the `ValidationRule` and implement the validation logic in your view model, for example by implementing the [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.